# Question about configuring sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, sharepoint-2007, tcp, named-pipes

When configuring a SQL 2005 Server in preparation for connectivity to a SharePoint Server 2007 farm, Microsoft recommends that Local and Remote Connections use both TCP/IP and named pipes. Where is this setting found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start > All Programs > Microsoft SQL Server 2005 > Configuration Tools > SQL Server Configuration Manager

Or simply

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\mmc.exe /32 "C:\WINDOWS\system32\SQLServerManager.msc"
```

Once there, in SQL Server 2005 Network Configuration you'll see the relevant options and with the right mouse button a contextual menu will let you choose the pertinent option.

There is probably some sp_configure parameter to enable this, but I haven't found that out.

In the Surface Area Configuration Tool (`"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Shared\SqlSAC.exe"`) it can be done as well, via "for Services and Connections" > Database Engine > Remote Connections

Comment: I thought its done from  SQL Server 2005 Surface Area Configuration tool??can u check one more time..

Comment: I'm certain this can be done where I told you. It can be done in the Surface Area Configuration Tool as well, in the "for Services and Connections > Database Engine > Remote Connections" section